# How to write file on another server in magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to create/write file on another server using Magento

Ex:
my site : www.test.com (Magento2site i want to write code here to generate file on www.testTEst.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ftp or sftp to write file in another server. I have used sftp to create file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class SftpActions
{
    protected $_sftp;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp $sftp
    ) {
        $this->_sftp = $sftp;
    }

    /**
     * @param obj $warehouse
     */
    public function saveFile( $data, $fileName, $exportedFolder )
    {
        $sftp = $this->loginSftp();

        if (!is_dir($exportedFolder))
        {
            $sftp->mkdir($exportedFolder, 0775);
        }
       $this->sftp->cd($exportedFolder);//the path is you will upload path
        $this->sftp->write($fileName, $data); // filename and string data or local file name
        $this->sftp->close();
    }

    /**
     * @return object $sftp
     */
    private function loginSftp()
    {
        $host = 'FTP Host';
        $port = 'FTP port';
        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password';

        $this->_sftp->open(
            array(
                'host' => $host.':'.$port,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password
            )
        );

        return $this->_sftp;
    }
}
```

Call `saveFile` function from anywhere with below params

```
$data = filedata
$fileName = filename (ex: test.txt)
$exportedFolder = folder path from root of the server
```

**Note:** You must enter your host, port, username and password in loginSftp function

Comment: Instead of $this->sftp in the saveFile function should be $sftp ?